# How to use Camel toD and netty4-http component? Problem with optimization of dinamic url

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I use Camel(2.23) dynamic routing toD(). I pass url "netty4-http:${property.url}" where url = "http://a-b-c.server.net:8888/service/v3" t.ex in toD(). After SendDynamicProcessor.process()
on expression.evaluate [:112] original url transforms to "netty4-http:http:a-b:8888/path". 
In source code I see the lines where transformation happens but I see no reason. Any idea?

How do you send requests with netty4-http component and dynamic url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have logged issue [CAMEL-13524](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13524).
As a workaround replace `toD` with `recipientList`.

```
.recipientList(simple("netty4-http:${property.url}"))
```

Comment: Tank you! You are so fast!